# Perl: Passing a URL in a query string

Tags: perl, url

I'm trying to pass a URL as a query string so it can be read by another website and then used:

```
www.example.com/domain?return_url=/another/domain
```

Gets returned as:

```
www.example.com/domain?return_url=%2Fanother%2Fdomain
```

Is there a way this URL can be read and parsed by the other application with the escaped characters?

The only way I can think of is to encode it somehow so it comes out like this:

www.example.com/domain?return_url=L2Fub3RoZXIvZG9tYWlu

then the other application can decode and use?

https://www.base64encode.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way would be to uri-encode the second hop as you do in your first example. The [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) and [`URI::QueryParam`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::QueryParam) modules make this nice and easy:

To encode a `URI`, you simply create a `URI` object on your base url. Then add any query parameters that you want. (NOTE: they will be automatically uri-encoded by `URI::QueryParam`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(say);

use URI;
use URI::QueryParam;

my $u = URI->new('http://www.example.com/domain');
$u->query_param_append('return_url', 'http://yahoo.com');

say $u->as_string;
# http://www.example.com/domain?return_url=http%3A%2F%2Fyahoo.com
```

To receive this url and then redirect to `return_url`, you simply create a new `URI` object then pull off the `return_url` query parameter with `URI::QueryParam`. (NOTE: again URI::QueryParam automatically uri-decodes the parameter for you):

```
my $u = URI->new(
  'http://www.example.com/domain?return_url=http%3A%2F%2Fyahoo.com'
);
my $return_url = $u->query_param('return_url');

say $return_url;
# http://yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 5):

> www.example.com/domain?return_url=%2Fanother%2Fdomain

This is called [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Not because you put a URL in it, but because it encodes characters that have a special meaning in a URL.

The `%2F` corresponds to a slash `/`. You've probably also seen the `%20` before, which is a space .

Putting a complete URI into a URL parameter of another URI is totally fine.

```
http://example.org?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Ffoo%3Fbar%3Dbaz
```

The application behind the URL you are calling needs to be able to understand URL encoding, but that is a trivial thing. Typical web frameworks and interfaces to the web (like [CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod) or [Plack](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack) in Perl) will do that. You should not have to care about it a all.

To URL-encode something in Perl, you have several options.

You could use the [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) module to create the whole URI including the URL encoded query.

```
use URI;

my $u = URI->new("http://example.org");
$u->query_form( return_url => "http://example.org/foo/bar?baz=qrr");

print $u;

__END__
http://example.org?return_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Ffoo%2Fbar%3Fbaz%3Dqrr
```

This seems like the natural thing to do.

You could also use the [URI::Encode](http://URI::Encode) module, which gives you a `uri_encode` function. That's useful if you want to encode strings without building a URI object.

> ```
> use URI::Encode qw(uri_encode uri_decode);
> my $encoded = uri_encode($data);
> my $decoded = uri_decode($encoded);
> ```

---

All of this is a normal part of how the web works. There is no need to do Base 64 encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would the application I'm sending it to actually use that encoded URL then to redirect elsewhere? :-

/domain decides to use that URL to go to http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Ffoo%2Fbar%3Fbaz%3Dqrr for example

Comment: Am I right in thinking /domain has to use uri_decode($return_url) and then redirect?